# what is UTF-8 code page equivalent of ASCII 128 to 160

Tags: utf-8, ascii

The UTF-8 code page  doesn't include the character of the rage 128 to 160 of Extended ASCII

what is the equivalent code in UTF-8 of this characters?

such as `Bullet, En dash, Em dash etc.`

Comment: Which character set do you mean exactly? "Extended ASCII" can mean a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this page. just search by name, code or almost anything you want.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm